# Delphi / RadStudio IDE not appearing after Windows 10 Insider 16184 update

Tags: delphi

I updated my Windows 10 from 16179 to 16184 and since then, the Delphi ide does not appear anymore, but bds.exe is running normal in task manager.
Anybody has any clue whats going on?
Delphi is the only application so far which does not start properly.
When I revert back to 16179, Delphi works again as usual.

Comment: Contact the vendor of the software for support. Only they can help I suspect. The sooner you tell them the sooner they can act. Then roll back. See also https://plus.google.com/101481629919677484324/posts/CiyJbBoAs7Z

Comment: This issue appears to have been reported in [Embarcadero's Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18058).